# Twilio – hanging up when the voicebox answers

Tags: twilio

I try to find a way how i can hang up an call if its rings for a while or the voice box picks up. Found this but doesn't really helps: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132587-Is-it-possible-to-hangup-a-call-after-a-certain-number-of-rings-

The Dial can only be used inside an active call. The other linked article doesn't help at all.
Is there a way to archive this? Also more 'hacky' ways are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [outbound-api calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#create-a-call-resource), you can look at timeout parameter, which determines how long to ring the dialed party (before they answer) until cancelling the call attempt.

For Answering Machines, you would use [Answering Machine Detection (AMD) or Human Detection](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-) (prompting for positive user input when the call is answered).